# Why node["application"] not working in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have written this block in one `setup` recipe

```
cookbook_file "ngin_conf_file" do
    path "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{node["application"]}"
     source "lvstaging"
     action :create
end
```

but it is treating as if node["application"] is `nil`.but it is accessible outside of cookbook_file block. How to get this works inside the block

Comment: Are you setting `node["application"]` somewhere in your recipe?

Comment: aws will set it automatically for us.. and its accessible in outside the resource block.

Comment: To Everyone : I resolved it like this

Comment: Like this what ? if you don't mind giving details

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a typo here (not linked to attribute), but would be easiest to confirm with a chef-run log of the error.

Your resource is named `ngin_conf_file` without an x at nginx and without extension but does not matter as you named the `source` specifically.

the `cookbook_file` resource will search a file named lvstaging here `<cookbook>/files/default/lvstaging`

If you have a complicated cookbook structure, it may search in others directory according to file specificity explained [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_cookbook_file.html#file-specificity)

I'll be happy to edit if its not the source cause, but again please provide a run log to help defining the problem.